# fetch APi request for forex rates

Tags: fetch

i'm a new developer trying to establish a connection with a free forex api service.  im able to establish the connection as when i inspect my console it says "success" and shows the rates for each currency, but now im struggling to take that forex rate data and display it on my browser.  I've tried creating a basic HTML code to store it with a unique ID name, but enhancing my script to place that forex rate inside the innerHTML is erroring out for me (browser displays "undefined" where the forex rate should show).  No other errors in the console, so i think im mapping the field wrong in my js. Any guidance be greatly appreciated!

Here is my javascript:

```
var EURUSD = document.querySelector("#EURUSD");
let url = 'https://api.exchangeratesapi.io/v1';

function params(paramsObj) {
    return new URLSearchParams({
      access_key: '<added my unique API key here',
      ...paramsObj
    });
}

function getLatest(options) {
  fetch(`${url}/latest?${params(options)}`)
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(displayData);

    function displayData(rates) {
        console.log(rates)
            EURUSD.innerText=`${rates.EUR}`
    }
}

// remove these if you want everything
getLatest({base: 'USD'});
```

here is a snippit from my browser console showing connectivity i believe (in my javascript above, based off below i thought i could do rates.CCY to pull specific rate):

```
{success: true, timestamp: 1711454285, base: 'USD', date: '2024-03-26', rates: {…}}
base
: 
"USD"
date
: 
"2024-03-26"
rates
: 
AED
: 
3.67229
AFN
: 
71.215413
ALL
: 
94.92401
AMD
: 
395.551886
```

here is my basic html:

```
<p id="EURUSD"></p>
```

here is an excerpt from their API Doc:

```
{
    "success":true,
    "fluctuation":true,
    "start_date":"2018-02-25",
    "end_date":"2018-02-26",
    "base":"EUR",
    "rates":{
        "USD":{
            "start_rate":1.228952,
            "end_rate":1.232735,
            "change":0.0038,
            "change_pct":0.3078
        },
        "JPY":{
            "start_rate":131.587611,
            "end_rate":131.651142,
            "change":0.0635,
            "change_pct":0.0483
        },
        [...]
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  In what way is your code not working as expected?  Please elaborate on the specific problem you are observing and what [debugging](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25385173/328193) you have done.  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.

Comment: This demo looks like it should work, but that depends on the format the API returns with. What is the error you are getting? As a bit of advise, I'd recommend using an ID instead of the class to find the element, as you will likely want to reuse the class elsewhere.

Comment: THanks Dan for your quick feedback, i changed the class to an ID, and tried to provide more specific detail above on the issue i am seeing in browser (undefined) and the specific format i think itslooking for?